# How do I load an fixture.yml in silverstripe?

Tags: silverstripe, fixtures, behat

I can't find it in the documentation : [Silverstripe-behat-extension](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-behat-extension)

I have a feature file that has some testing scripts. Now I want to fill some test content in a temp database.

So I create a yml file that puts the content in the database.
But how do I load the yml file in my features file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your feature use:

`Background:
    Given a file "/absolute/path/my-data-fixture.yml"`